# What's the word for paper "decaying"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, verbs

Imagine an old map, a map with a path to a treasure, like the ones you remember from cartoons. The map's partially destroyed, because it's so old, and it has been exposed to air, and heat, and water, and people touching it, you name it.

My question is: what **happened** to the paper?  Which **verb** describes it best? I mean the proces of paper getting thinner and more delicate, to the point where a touch can make it turn into powder. Does paper *decay*? *Decompose*? I guess not in this case, as the two IMHO refer to what happens when bacteria "feed" on organic matter. So what is it?

Comment: "Disintegrate" might often apply to paper.

Comment: "Aging" applies fairly well to paper; it's a cop out, since you seem to be wanting a specific term, but a general term like "aged map" or "ancient volume of forgotten lore" (with apologies to E.A. Poe) can evoke the reader's/listener's imagination quite well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One word that I feel is *particularly* associated with age-related deterioration of paper-based products is...

> [**moulder**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/moulder#moulder) (US [**molder**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/molder#molder)) - slowly decay or disintegrate, especially because of neglect.
>   OxfordDctionaries example usage: *'the smell of mouldering books'*
>   Plus several examples from Google Books of [*"mouldered books"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mouldered%20books%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22mouldered%20books%22&tbm=bks)

Comment: I think that _moulder_ should be restricted to cases where the paper is actually being attacked/consumed by mold (fungi). It's common, but needs some moisture (not just age) to proceed.

Comment: @Phil: I agree that strictly speaking *mouldered* implies *moisture* and age, more strongly than [Jim's *"foxed*"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/180450/2637) (which you might use even if there's been no "significant" dampness). But for me at least, *moulder* works in more different contexts. I could easily imagine *"Wrap the family heirloom bible up tightly before storage, or it will moulder [away]"*. But I really can't get my head around *"...or it will fox"*.

Comment: I'm not sure the etymology of moulder/molder actually stems from "mould". It simply means to crumble/disintegrate.

Comment: @Pete: Consulting OED, I see you appear to be right. Apparently the verb **to moulder** derives from an OE noun that originally meant (more or less) "crumbly topsoil, earth". Our current **mould = the fungussy stuff** (one of 5 different noun entries) has a different (somewhat uncertain) etymology probably deriving from an old Danish regionalism meaning "to rot, decay".

Answer (score 28):

Paper *rots* or *mildews* if it gets damp, it *yellows* with age, and perhaps it *crumbles*.

Comment: "Crumble" is pretty, pretty, pretty, pretty good...

Comment: Good ones!  "Turns brittle" is also used to describe crumbling paper, when it loses its suppleness to bend.

Comment: @Kristina: I've no special knowledge here, but it seems to me only relatively modern cheap paper *crumbles* after a few decades. I'm guessing short fibres in recycled wood, and the rarity of cloth, etc., in the paper are factors here. Really old bibles don't normally crumble - they just get blotchy stains and eaten-away edges.

Comment: The fragments of the Dead Sea Scrolls look pretty moth-eaten, though I don't suppose moths were actually involved.

Comment: Old paper (whether wood or rag based), and high-priced specialty papers today, are _acid free_. Cheap modern paper has high acid content that makes it deteriorate/embrittle very quickly. The DSS may even have been vellum (calfskin?) based.

Comment: It may also be _weathered_ by time.

Answer (score 23):

I think  [deteriorate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Deteriorate) may be an appropriate verb to use:

> (intr) to wear away or disintegrate

[Maps deterioration](http://www.naa.gov.au/records-management/agency/preserve/physical-preservation/maps-and-plans.aspx)

> Preserving maps and plans - Preservation and storage -
>
> Deterioration of materials over time is inevitable, but we can control how fast it happens. Some materials are susceptible to deterioration because of their composition and others as a result of storage conditions.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paper%20crumbles,paper%20deteriorates,%20paper%20rots&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,paper%20crumbles;,c0;.t1;,paper%20deteriorates;,c0;.t1;,paper%20rots;,c0): use of a few common verbs related to paper deterioration.

Comment: Close, but I think it's too general.

Answer (score 11):

40 years of experience in printing and photography - we refer to paper 'deteriorating' in a process of 'degradation'.  Paper manufacturers have long known that acid in paper is one of the main causes of this process and alkaline papers are much more long lasting and less likely to yellow and age.

The use of alum sizes in papermaking was discontinued because of the acidification this treatment introduces and simply handling paper introduces lactic acid from sweat on the hands. Those organisations dedicated to the preservation of paper based records use a process of alkaline washing to preserve valuable documents.

See the following from [Royal Society of Chemistry - Saving Paper](http://www.rsc.org/education/eic/issues/2013March/paper-conservation-cellulose-acid-hydrolysis.asp)

Comment: I like the suggestion of the word *degradation* (or the verb *degrade*).  But the discussion of how degradation actually occurs, while interesting, is off-topic for English.SE and not relevant to the question at hand.

Answer (score 10):

One term for age-related spotting etc is [foxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foxing)

Comment: All my life I've used ["slightly foxed"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22slightly+foxed%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) with the vague sense of *tatty/stale/putrid* (often, of foodstuffs and the like). I'm also familiar with it used metaphorically (*drunk*, and *past one's prime of life*). But I never knew until now that it's got specific origins in old blotchy stained paper. I always thought the usage was "slangy", and if I ever encountered references to *foxed photographs*, I probably assumed it was supposed to be ***fogged***. You learn something new every day, ty!

Comment: It's very tempting to attribute "fox" to "Ferric OXide" since apparently these are often rust spots.

Comment: Actually, I've just checked (the real) OED on this one. It seems ***to fox** = to intoxicate, befuddle. Also (? nonce-use), to redden (one's nose) with drinking* was first recorded 1611 (dunno if that's on account of foxes being reddish). The *fox = delude, puzzle* sense was first recorded 50 years later. In 1743 there's *foxed = *of beer: Turned sour.* But it's not until 1847 that we get *foxed = of the leaves of books, also of timber; Discoloured by decay; stained with brownish-yellow spots.* My guess is some figurative uses relate to the fox's typical colour. I doubt Fe2O3 figures in it!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Perhaps the animal is so named due to its colour being so similar to the colour of rust. A plausible etymology if I ever heard one.

Comment: @dotancohen: Given that ***fox*** was an "English" word about 1000 years before Anglophones even grasped the *concept* of ***oxide*** in order to create terms like ***ferric oxide***, I think it's an unlikely etymology. But you may think I have a rather blinkered view of such things, since I don't even believe in time travel (***yet**!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You are absolutely correct. The compound itself was obviously named after the animal with which it shares a colour! Thus the contrived usage of Latin "Ferrum" as opposed to simply "Iron".

Answer (score 4):

Occasionally, people have used the word ***weather*** as a verb for scenarios where something exposed to elements has been deteriorated or degraded.

> The ancient parchment was so ***weathered*** that it crumbled in his hands.

Answer (score 3):

fray:

> v. to unravel or become worn at the edge, typically through constant rubbing.

This word captures the physical wearing but doesn't relate to the organic decaying as you mentioned. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility (although not specific to paper) is ***erodes***. 
Also, this may not be what you’re looking for, but paper (with information printed on it) that is exposed to light (and heat?) over a period of time ***fades***.

Comment: I would perhaps expect the ink to fade, rather than the paper. I have found that papers tend to yellow and darken. Good word, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are two attempts to distinguish among several common synonyms related to this question. From *Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*, Eleventh Edition (2003), addressing the words **decay**, **decompose**, **rot**, **putrefy**, and **spoil**, all of which "mean to undergo destructive dissolution":

> DECAY implies a slow change from a state of soundness or perfection ("a *decaying* mansion"). DECOMPOSE stresses a breaking down by chemical change and when applied to organic matter a corruption ("the strong odor of *decomposing* vegetation"). ROT is a close synonym of DECOMPOSE and often connotes foulness ("fruit was left to *rot* in the warehouse"). PUTREFY implies the rotting of animal matter and offensiveness to sight and smell ("corpses *putrefying* on the battlefield"). SPOIL applies chiefly to the decomposition of foods (""keep the ham from *spoiling*).

And from S. I. Hayakawa, *Choose the Right Word: A Modern Guide to Synonyms* (1968), addressing the words **rot**, **decay**, **decompose**, **molder**, **putrefy**, and **spoil**, all of which "refer to the breakdown of dead organic tissues by natural bacterial processes":

> **Rot** is the least formal and most forceful of these words, suggesting an advanced point in this process of breakdown; the tissues at this point might or might not be foul-smelling but they would in any case be almost unrecognizable, as compared to their former state: [examples omitted]. **Spoil**, by contrast, refers to an earlier point in the process of organic breakdown; it is especially applied to foods that have turned "bad" or begun to turn: [examples omitted].
>
> **Decay** is a more matter-of-fact word than *rot*, and applies to the whole process of breakdown, but particularly to the end point of total destruction: [examples omitted]. **Decompose** is a more formal substitute for *decay*, but is almost clinical in its reference to a point in the process between *spoil* and *rot* at which point tissues may be distended and ruptured by a build-up of gases: [examples omitted].
>
> **Putrefy** refers to the same point of the process as decompose, stressing particularly the presence of foul or poisonous gases and noxious odors: [examples omitted]. **Molder** might now be thought too precious or euphemistic a substitute for *decay*. It means to *decay* gradually and turn into dust: [examples omitted].

Merriam-Webster and Hayakawa seem to agree that *decay* is the broadest term, since it takes the affected organic object from a state of fitness to one of dissolution. But in other respects, Merriam-Webster focuses on the categories of objects that the various synonyms particularly apply to, while Hayakawa focuses on what he considers the stage of disintegration associated with each synonym.

The odd term out is *molder*, which Merriam-Webster ignores, and which Hayakawa deems potentially "too precious or euphemistic"—perhaps because (in 1968) the most familiar instance of *molder* to American English speakers was probably in the folk lyric "John Brown's body lies a-moldering in the grave [but his truth is marching on]." But to me, the process of gradual decay from wholeness to dust seems an especially appropriate way to describe the gradual disintegration of paper, so I endorse FumbleFingers's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To become **pulverulent** is to **[dry rot](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mwc/18299/dry)** (fungus disease which attacks timber, also is [saprobic](http://english_contemporary.enacademic.com/58862/dry_rot) to wallpaper)

> 1795 1. a. a decay of seasoned timber caused by fungi that consume the cellulose of wood leaving a soft skeleton which is
>   readily **reduced to powder**

To decay in **moisture**, is to **[ret](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/111934/ret)**

> (also rate) (retted, retting) 1 tr. soften (flax, hemp, etc.) by
>   soaking or by exposure to moisture. 2 intr. (often as retted adj.) (of
>   hay etc.) be spoilt by wet or rot.

Comment: *Dry rot* is a fungus disease that attacks wood, but I have never heard of it attacking books.

Comment: @PeterShor dry rot     "fungus disease which attacks timber and wallpaper"  Wallpaper was actually made of paper, and not the commercially prepared synthetic blends.  Paper made of pulp, not linen.-http://english_contemporary.enacademic.com/58862/dry_rot

Comment: *wallpaper* is not *books*.

Comment: @PeterShor Leaving aside the discussion... This is some powerful stuff: "wallpaper is not books" :)

Answer (score -1):

[*embrittled*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/embrittled) is a word which means that something has deteriorated to the point that a slight pressure can break it into pieces.